# How to right align level field in Python logging.Formatter

Tags: python, logging, formatting, python-logging

I'm currently trying to right align the logging level field in my Python logger so that output such as:

```
[2011-10-14 13:47:51] [DEBUG] --- starting... (smtphandlers.py:96)
[2011-10-14 13:47:51] [INFO] --- first things first... (smtphandlers.py:97)
[2011-10-14 13:47:51] [WARNING] --- about to end... (smtphandlers.py:98)
[2011-10-14 13:47:51] [DEBUG] --- ending (smtphandlers.py:99)
```

instead looks like:

```
[2011-10-14 13:47:51] [   DEBUG] --- starting... (smtphandlers.py:96)
[2011-10-14 13:47:51] [    INFO] --- first things first... (smtphandlers.py:97)
[2011-10-14 13:47:51] [ WARNING] --- about to end... (smtphandlers.py:98)
[2011-10-14 13:47:51] [   DEBUG] --- ending (smtphandlers.py:99)
```

The format line for the first block is:

```
logging.Formatter("[%(asctime)s] [%(levelname)s] --- %(message)s (%(filename)s:%(lineno)s)", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

If I know the max level length is 8 (eg: CRITICAL), then I'll right align to 8 spaces.
I'm trying to figure out how to achieve this.  The following fails because "%(levelname)s" is more than 8 characters (the substitution doesn't happen until later).  If I use something like "{0:>20}".format"%(levelname)s", then it works, but that is more padding than I need or want.

```
logging.Formatter("[%(asctime)s] [" + "{0:>8}".format"%(levelname)s" + "] --- %(message)s (%(filename)s:%(lineno)s)", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Short of subclassing Formatter, anyone have a way to achieve this?

Comment: The ```%(...)s``` is called [printf-style String Formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting). We're able to adjust the string width by setting the "minimum field width" or left align the content by using a "```-```" (dash or hyphen) "conversion flags".

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Like this:

```
logging.Formatter("[%(asctime)s] [%(levelname)8s] --- %(message)s (%(filename)s:%(lineno)s)", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

---

**PS:** If you would like INFO to be left aligned, you can use `[%(levelname)-8s]` instead.

Comment: @AlexL What about center aligned?

Comment: @JoeVictor Late to the party but this can be done by setting the `style` parameter for the Formatter object to `{` and doing something like `[{levelname:^8s}]`.

Answer (score 16):

Try with this format line :

```
logging.Formatter("[%(asctime)s] [%(levelname)8s] --- %(message)s (%(filename)s:%(lineno)s)", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

python logger formatter use the standard python [string formatting rules](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

Comment: `%8(levelname)s` won't work, it needs to be `%(levelname)8s`.