# Python logging.Formatter(): is there any way to fix the width of a field and justify it left/right?

Tags: python, logging, formatting, python-logging

Here's a sample of log records from the logging tutorial:

```
2005-03-19 15:38:55,977 - simpleExample - DEBUG - debug message
2005-03-19 15:38:55,979 - simpleExample - INFO - info message
2005-03-19 15:38:56,054 - simpleExample - WARNING - warn message
2005-03-19 15:38:56,055 - simpleExample - ERROR - error message
2005-03-19 15:38:56,130 - simpleExample - CRITICAL - critical message
```

This trailing jaggedness annoys me to no end.

I really want to be able to format like this:

```
2005-03-19 15:38:55,977 - simpleExample -    DEBUG - debug message
2005-03-19 15:38:55,979 - simpleExample -     INFO - info message
2005-03-19 15:38:56,054 - simpleExample -  WARNING - warn message
2005-03-19 15:38:56,055 - simpleExample -    ERROR - error message
2005-03-19 15:38:56,130 - simpleExample - CRITICAL - critical message
```

I've attempted the following for my logger, which doesn't work (abbreviated code):

```
fmt = "{0:>8}"
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s %(filename)s: " + fmt.format("%(levelname)s") + " %(message)s", "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
```

This executes fine and prints the level name as always, but it doesn't implement the width format.

Ex.

```
logger.debug("testing debug message")
logger.info("some random info")
logger.critical("oh crap!")
```

**Actual result:**

```
2013/12/16 13:43:10 logtester: DEBUG testing debug message
2013/12/16 13:43:10 logtester: INFO some random info
2013/12/16 13:43:10 logtester: CRITICAL oh crap!
```

**Desired result:**

```
2013/12/16 13:43:10 logtester:    DEBUG testing debug message
2013/12/16 13:43:10 logtester:     INFO some random info
2013/12/16 13:43:10 logtester: CRITICAL oh crap!
```

Any hints to implement a fixed width of a field in a logging.Formatter()?

Using Python 2.6.9.

**EDIT**: second attempt using another method:

```
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s %(filename)s: " + "%(foo)5s" % {"foo" : "(%(levelname)s)"} + " %(message)s", "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Still results in:

```
2013/12/16 13:43:10 logtester: DEBUG testing debug message
2013/12/16 13:43:10 logtester: INFO some random info
2013/12/16 13:43:10 logtester: CRITICAL oh crap!
```

Maybe I'm just doing something boneheaded.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to right align level field in Python logging.Formatter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771912/how-to-right-align-level-field-in-python-logging-formatter)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Field width can be specified by adding a number in front of the type specifier:

```
>>> "%(foo)8s" % {'foo': 'bar'}
'     bar'
```

You can use this in your format string passed to the formatter. For your example, that'd be:

```
"%(asctime)s %(filename)s: %(levelname)8s %(message)s"
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as a parameter in Formatter().  formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s %(filename)s: " + "%(foo)5s" % {"foo" : "(%(levelname)s)"} + " %(message)s", "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S") has the same result.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing the format operation yourself - just use the field width syntax in the string you're passing. E.g. `%(levelname)8s`.

Answer (score 14):

Logging (as of 3.2) provides improved support for bracket string format styles. For example, you can now use this kind of formatting:

```py
fomatter = logging.Formatter('{asctime} {name} {levelname:^8s} {message}', style='{')
```

Which produces center aligned log level. I don't think this is possibile with % formatted strings.

```
2021-10-19 14:27:05,799 __main__  DEBUG   Debug message
2021-10-19 14:27:05,800 __main__   INFO   Info message
2021-10-19 14:27:05,800 __main__ WARNING  Warning message
2021-10-19 14:27:05,801 __main__  ERROR   Error message
```

and

`'{asctime} {name} {levelname:<8s} {message}'`
to align right

```
2021-10-19 14:26:45,408 __main__    DEBUG Debug message
2021-10-19 14:26:45,409 __main__     INFO Info message
2021-10-19 14:26:45,410 __main__  WARNING Warning message
2021-10-19 14:26:45,410 __main__    ERROR Error message
```

or

`'{asctime} {name} {levelname:>8s} {message}'`
to align left

```
2021-10-19 14:26:25,761 __main__ DEBUG    Debug message
2021-10-19 14:26:25,761 __main__ INFO     Info message
2021-10-19 14:26:25,762 __main__ WARNING  Warning message
2021-10-19 14:26:25,762 __main__ ERROR    Error message
```

Comment: Think you mixed the right and left align. e.g.: `x = "test";
print(f".{x:>9}.")` prints `.     test.`, i.e. aligns to the right.